# adding rows in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keylistener, tablemodel

```
 this.tModel.insertRow(rowCount,new Object[]  {"","","",""});    
 this.table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
 this.table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);

 this.table.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
               rowCount = this.table.getSelectedRow() + 1;
               tModel.insertRow(rowCount,new Object[]{"", "","",""}); 
          }
      }
 });
```

I am trying to create a jtable adding rows at run time on mouse click. i alredy added a default row. but i cant get selection on that row. and i want to change the selection to newly added row when added on the key pressed action?
please suggest an answer? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your actual question.

Comment: actually i want default selection over my first row

Comment: how about setSelectedRow(int) method !? don't really know what's your desire here...

Comment: what u mean by setSelectedRow(int) ?

Comment: In order to set/change the row selection, you can use [`JTable#setRowSelectionInterval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would encourage you to use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), `KeyListener` is a low level API and events can be consumed before you ever see them.

To change/set the row selection in a `JTable`, you should use [JTable#setRowSelectionInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29)

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "enter");
ActionMap am = getActionMap();
am.put("enter", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int rowCount = table.getSelectedRow() + 1;
        tModel.insertRow(rowCount,new Object[]{"", "","",""});                 
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount, rowCount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the last entry in a table, you could use a method like this:

```
private void selectLastPossibleEntry() {
    final int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
    final int selectedRowCount = jTable.getSelectedRowCount();
    if (rowCount > 0 && selectedRowCount <= 1) // we do not want do destroy multiple selected lines by the user
        jTable.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount - 1, rowCount - 1);
}
```

or more general:

```
private void selectLastPossibleEntryForJTable(final JTable jTable) {
    final int rowCount = jTable.getModel().getRowCount();
    final int selectedRowCount = jTable.getSelectedRowCount();
    if (rowCount > 0 && selectedRowCount <= 1) // we do not want do destroy multiple selected lines by the user
        jTable.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount - 1, rowCount - 1);
}
```

Hint: This does not take care of different sortings