# Select multiple rows in JTable only with mouse

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I have a JTable, and left clicking with the mouse and scrolling through the table, I want to select a number of lines, obviously without using the keyboard. After, I would like to take the indexes of the selected lines with `jTable.getSelectedRows();`  method. How could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the table set up for multiple selection, you can CTR+click and shift+click to select multiple rows

Comment: Yes, I know but I want to use only the mouse

Comment: Well, two obvious things come to find, your need a `MouseListener` and you need to update the `ListSelectionModel` via the `add/setRowSelectionInterval` methods of the `JTable` ... as a starting point

Comment: Can you give me some code please?

Comment: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (possibly [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) and [`JTable` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) should give you everything you need to get started

Comment: [Example of `setRowSelectionInterval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137091/adding-rows-in-jtable/13137487#13137487) - using key bindings, but the same priniciple. See where all that takes, if you have a particular issue with any of that, post a question demonstrating your efforts and we'll see if we can't guide you to a solution